# jquery validation ignorar un campo dependiendo de la selección

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

habra alguna función validate de jquery validation que ignore el requerido de un input dependiendo de la selección de un campo anterior

Tengo un select2 dependiendo de lo que seleccione alli quiero que el rule required sea true o false

Comment: puedes usar algo como esto : $('input[name="mi_input"]').rules('remove', 'required');

Comment: ¿Podrías poner tu código (JS+CSS+HTML)?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que seria asi:

Creas el select con sus option con un parametro que sólo usarás tu y se puede llamar "REL":

```
<select id="selector1">
   <option value="1" rel="required">Opcion A</option>
   <option value="2" rel="required">Opcion B</option>
   <option value="3">Opcion C</option>
   <option value="4">Opcion D</option>
</select>

<select id="selector2">
   .....
</select>

$('#selector1').onchange(function() {
    // Lees este campo especial de la opción seleccionada
    var valor_seleccionado = $('#select1').find('option:selected').attr('rel');

    // Si lees un option que tiene el required, valor_seleccionado devuelve required, sinó, devuelve undefined
    if (valor_seleccionado == 'required'){
        $('#selector2').attr('required', true);
    } else {
        $('#selector2').attr('required', false);
    }
});
```

NOTA: También puedes simplificar el ultimo IF comparativo así:

$('#selector2').attr('required', (valor_seleccionado == 'required'));

Esto lo puedes aplicar a cualquier campo del formulario.

Espero que sea esto.
Saludos.